# Picture is blank if I try to download it from blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

This is how I try to upload a photo to blob storage so when I see the image of what it looks like when I try to upload, it's empty and it says "We can not open this file"

In other words, it is empty that can be seen in the picture below.

[image: blob storage]
You can also see that the image size is 0 B

So the question is how can it be that it does not upload any picture?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileToNews(AdminViewModel model)
{
    AzureBlob AzureBlobInfo = new AzureBlob();
    var namevalue = model.NameValue;
    var fValue = model.FileToUpload.FileName;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(namevalue) && fValue != null && fValue.Length > 0)
    {
        var name = UrlFriendlySEO.Url(model.NameValue);//make this name SEO friendly here.
        var filename = AzureBlobInfo.FullImagesName(name);

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth.StorageCredentials(Accountname, KeyValue), true);
        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        // Retrieve a reference to a container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ContainerValue);

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filename);
        using (var f = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fValue))
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(f);
        }


    }
    return RedirectToAction("UploadFileToNews");
    }
```

Comment: Duplicate as marked by Gaurav.